# 辞書に内包されているリストの削除について

Tags: python, python3

```
list=[]
dict={}
key=sq{}.format(moji)
list.append(su)
dict[key] = list
```

として

```
{'あ': ['10', '20'], 'い': ['11', '21']}
```

となるように辞書の中にリストを内包しました。
ここでキーとなる`'い'`とリストの`['11', '21']`を削除したいのですが

```
dict[key].pop()
list.pop()
```

とすると`'い'`は削除されて様な感じになるのですが
同じキーの`'い'`を作成されると`: ['11', '31']`となり最後の内容だけ削除されてしまい

```
list.Clear()
```

をするとすべての内容が削除されてしまいます。

```
'い': ['11', '21']
```

だけを完全に削除する方法をご教授頂けないでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 発生している現象について、文章での説明だけでなく、他者が問題を再現できるようにしたプログラムソース全体を掲載してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

[list](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#list) や [dict](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict) は組み込み型に存在するので, 別の名前にしたほうがよいでしょう

「マッピング型 --- dict」の説明にもあるように
キーを削除するなら, 次の方法で行います

```py
d = {'あ': ['10', '20'], 'い': ['11', '21']}
k = 'い'
del d[k]
print(d)
```

キーが存在するかどうか不明な場合は, 以下のようにチェックできます

```py
if 'い' in d:
    del d['い']
```

---

#### 追記

キーに対してそれぞれのリストを管理するのなら, 以下のような感じで

```py
lst = d['あ']
lst.append('300')

# あるいは
for k in d:
    lst = d[k]
    lst.pop()
# またあるいは
for k,lst in d.items():
    print(f'キー: {k}, リスト: {lst}')
    lst.append('A')
```

Comment: del d[k]ではキーは消えますがリストが残ったままとなり同じキーを作成すると内容が追加されてしまいます。'い': ['11', '21','31'･･･]ので頭を悩ませております。

Comment: @小塚重治 さん、先に質問にコメントしたように、その「キーは消えますが」「同じキーを作成する」と「内容が追加されてしまいます」というプログラムソース全体を、他者が再現出来るように質問に追記してみてください。今のままだと貴方が直面している問題を、他の人は推測や仮定でしか扱えないと思われます。

Comment: 上記 `del d[k]` で `'い': ['11', '21']` は削除されます。「リストが残ったまま」「内容が追加」は, そのように**作成されている**から。現在の処理がどうなっているか, どのような結果を期待しているのか, 質問の内容からはこれ以上読み取れません

Comment: 多変申し訳御座いません。del d[k]で'い': ['11', '21'] は削除されましたが、list.append(su)としているためlistは内容が残ったままであることが解りました。できればキー毎にリストが作成したかったのですが現在のやり方ではリストは一つで単にキーだけが作成されるようですね。キー毎にリストは作成できるのでしょうか。方法があれば教えて頂ければ幸いです。